Is $\rho = \sum_{j} p_j|n_j\rangle\langle n_j|$ a valid construction for any mixed state?
I have a mixed state $\rho$ and its hamiltonian $H$. Firstly, I find the eigenvalues $\{p_j\}$ of $\rho$, and orthonormal basis of $H$. I write $\rho$ in terms of $H$'s eigenstates and $\rho$'s eigenvalues as:
$$
\rho = \sum_{j} p_j|n_j\rangle\langle n_j| \hspace{2em} (1)
$$
My question is: is equation (1) a valid construction for any mixed states? Any help would be appreciated, thank you in advance.

What do you mean by a mixed state and its Hamiltonian"? Generically, a Hamiltonian and the state it acts upon are initially not associated, and there's no reason to think that $\rho$ should be diagonal in the basis of $H$.

Yes, indeed, but that's an important aspect of your question.

The question is, how do you perform the diagonalisation routine? A typical way to achieve this is to have a set of unitaries $\{U_i\}$ for which the $|n_j\rangle$ are eigenstates with $\pm 1$ eigenvalues. If, for example, there's a pair $j,k$ of them with opposite eigenvalues for $U_i$, then choosing to apply $U_i$ 50:50 at random cancels the off-diagonal term $|n_j\rangle\!\langle n_k|$. Setting aside any question of finding a modestly sized set of $\{U_i\}$ and implementing them, whatever your protocol, you're going to need some randomness in there. A typical way of thinking about this is to have an extra qubit. Whether you prepare it in a $|+\rangle$ state or a maximally mixed state doesn't matter, but you then do a controlled-$U_i$ off that qubit.
What I'm saying is that, ultimately, to perform the diagonalisation step, you're going to have to introduce an ancilla system.

I haven't thought about how to do diagonalisation using unitaries. Do you have some papers about this technique? thank you very much!!

I've never previously thought about it as generally as I stated it in my answer (so have no idea where it might have appeared in the literature in this form) but it's a common technique, starting from the fact that dephasing noise diagaonalises (in the computational basis) a density matrix. But it also appears in magic state distillation and studies of graph-diagonal states (for example, you make an entanglement witness for a graph diagonal state, and you can equally apply it to any non-diagonal state). Section 2.E of https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0405045 might help.

I have a question like this: can the operation of converting from pure state to density matrix $|\psi\rangle -> |\psi\rangle \langle \psi|$ be understood as a quantum operation? Currently, I have to measure the state  $|\psi\rangle = \sum_{j} \sqrt{p_j}|n_j\rangle$ to attain a probability vector so that I can calculate equation 1. My opinion is that when I do a measurement, it will stop being quantum (the final state can't exist on quantum computers). Is that right? Whereas in double systems, you have partial trace operations which are basically quantum observables.

There is no operation that converts $|\psi\rangle\rightarrow|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|$. They are the same thing just written using different formalisms.

I suspect you're thinking about destructive, projective measurements where there's a number of projectors equal to the dimension of the Hilbert space. There are also partial measurements where not all projectors are rank 1. Performed in a non-destructive way, they can achieve some of what you're looking for.
